# Php is it possible to create an universal algorithm that puts JOINED tables to nested array?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, join, group-by

Lets imagine something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM products LEFT JOIN prices ON prices.PRODUCT_ID = products.ID;
```

and this gives:

```
ID: 1; NAME: 'product with no price';   PRODUCT_ID: null; PRICE: null;
ID: 2; NAME: 'product with one price';  PRODUCT_ID: 2;    PRICE: 1000;
ID: 3; NAME: 'product with two prices'; PRODUCT_ID: 3;    PRICE: 2000;
ID: 3; NAME: 'product with two prices'; PRODUCT_ID: 3;    PRICE: 2500;
```

and this algorithm should produce:

```
array:
 product => (
  [0]
   id = 1
   name = product with no price
   prices = array()
  [1]
   id = 2
   name = product with one price
   prices = array(
    product_id: 2,
    price: 1000
   )
  [2]
   id = 3
   name = product with two prices
   prices = array(
    array(product_id: 3,
    price: 2000),
    array(product_id: 3,
    price: 2500)
   )
```

and lets not forget about transitive joins. So price -> product, but can be commentOnPrice -> price -> product.
Is it possible to create that complicated algorithm?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Just transpose the result array. That's a simple `foreach` *and* if you wrap it into a function or object, you can specify the fields as variables. Universal enough? If you have problems to do that just search for array and group on this website.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't do that**. Results from queries are *linear* meaning they can't be grouped to what you want. They are single-dimensional array.

The best way to do that is to manually format it on you `PHP` code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT function and retrieve prices in strings separated with ','(in my example):

```
SELECT products.ID, products.NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(prices.PRICE) FROM products 
LEFT JOIN prices ON prices.PRODUCT_ID = products.ID 
GROUP BY products.ID, products.NAME
```

You will get something like(db I created for this example)

> ID    NAME    GROUP_CONCAT(prices.PRICE,',')
>
> 1 product with no price   [BLOB -> 0B]
>
> 2 product with two prices 200,400
>
> 3 product with one price  34

Then, in php, explode grouped field by ',' and create arrays of prices